# Mocha afterEach hooks called in wrong order

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a set of tests written with Mocha. To do some basic setup and teardown for each test run, I use root hooks. Per the test file, there are additional beforeEach and afterEach hooks.
The expected order would be:

```
root beforeEach
file beforeEach
test
file beforeEach
root beforeEach
```

But what I got is:

```
root beforeEach
file beforeEach
test
root beforeEach
file beforeEach
```

The simplified code looks like this:

```js
// mocha-hooks.ts
export const mochaHooks = {
    beforeEach() {
        console.log('root beforeEach');
    },

    afterEach() {
        console.log('root afterEach');
    },
};
```

```js
// sample.spec.ts
beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('file beforeEach');
});
afterEach(() => {
    console.log('file afterEach');
});
```

The project is written in Typescript and uses ts-mocha for the test execution.
I already tried the legacy method with a file that contains a call to `beforeEach` and the new method of the exported `mochaHooks` object.

What is the point I'm missing?